# Yii Bootstrap Gridview and CSqlDataProvider has no $data variable.

Tags: yii

Below I have included some code from my model and my view. It tells me that the $date variable does not exist. I dont understand why it wouldnt. I am changing over from it being objects so thats why some of the old code still has $data-> and why its being changed to $data['']. Regardless its now telling me that $data does not exist.

This is the code from my view.

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type'=>'condensed',
    'dataProvider'=>$gridDataProvider,
    'template'=>"{items}",
    'columns'=>array(
        array('name'=>'id', 'header'=>'Name'),
        array('name'=>'emax', 'header'=>'Employees' 'value'=>$date['id']),
        /*array('name'=>'location', 'value'=>'$data->city . ", " . $data->state->name', 'header'=>'Location'),
        array('name'=>'phone', 'header'=>'Phone'),
        array('name'=>'website', 'header'=>'Website'),
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 50px'),
            'template'=>"{view}",
            'buttons'=>array(
                'view'=>array(
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("account/rinkdetail", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                    ),
                ),
        ),*/
    ),
));
?>
```

This is the code from my model

```
$sql="SELECT buyer.id, emax.max as emax, emin.min as emin, rmin.min as rmin, rmin.max as rmax, firm.name as firm, region.name as region, project.name as project
FROM buyer
LEFT JOIN buyer_target target on buyer.id=target.buyer_id
LEFT JOIN employee emax on emax.id=target.max_employee_id
LEFT JOIN employee emin on emin.id=target.min_employee_id
LEFT JOIN revenue rmax on rmax.id=target.max_revenue_id
LEFT JOIN revenue rmin on rmin.id=target.min_revenue_id
LEFT JOIN buyer_target_firm tfirm on buyer.id=tfirm.buyer_id
LEFT JOIN firm on firm.id=tfirm.firm_id
LEFT JOIN buyer_target_project tproject on buyer.id=tproject.buyer_id
LEFT JOIN project on project.id=tproject.project_id
LEFT JOIN buyer_target_region tregion on buyer.id=tregion.buyer_Id
LEFT JOIN region on region.id=tregion.region_id";
$gridDataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql);
return $gridDataProvider;
```

Comment: I tried doing it as a CArrayDataProvider and it came up with the same issue. Worked fine when I was using active record for the data but not when using sql.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. In my example used above it was saying

```
'value'=>$date['id']
```

Even though I had DATE in my example, I was using DATA in my actual test. 
What the actual problem was it that it needs to be...

```
'value'=>'$data["id"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
array('name'=>'emax', 'header'=>'Employees' 'value'=>$date['id']),
```

With:

```
array('name'=>'emax', 'header'=>'Employees', 'value'=>$date['id']),
```